# Calculating p-value with regression output

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics

I am given a regression output shown below:

```
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.91571 -0.33951  0.09489  0.43068  1.49429 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.55870    0.13802   11.29   NA
act          0.05780    0.00555   10.41   NA
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.591 on 703 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1337,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1324 
F-statistic: 108.5 on 1 and 703 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I need to calculate the p-value with only this information. I tried estimate/t-value but I am get a higher number than I anticipated given the p-value of the model. Any thoughts?

Comment: In a t-test, how do you calculate the p-value?

Comment: This looks like homework or something similar. Please read the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag info in relation to your question. ... "*I need to calculate the p-value*" -- '*the*' p-value of which quantity?